# Converting ruby hashes to JSON that is both valid and human readable

Tags: ruby, json, hash

I have code that works but am soliciting suggestions for improvement.

I have a file containing ruby hashes:

```
{"dat"=>"2013-09-01T20:40:00-07:00", "sca"=>"5", "del"=>"755", "dir"=>"S"}
{"dat"=>"2013-09-01T21:00:00-07:00", "sca"=>"5", "del"=>"459", "dir"=>"S"}
```

that I want to convert to JSON that is both valid and human-readable.  This code is compact and produces valid JSON...

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# expected input:   file of hashes, one/line
# output:       properly formatted json array

require 'json'

json_array = []

while input = ARGF.gets
    input.each_line do |line|
        json_array.push( eval(line) )   
    end  
end
print json_array
puts
```

..but without any newlines is not easily human-readable:

```
[{"dat"=>"2013-09-01T20:40:00-07:00", "sca"=>"5", "del"=>"755", "dir"=>"S"}, {"dat"=>"2013-09-01T21:00:00-07:00", "sca"=>"5", "del"=>"459", "dir"=>"S"}]
```

Substituting

```
puts JSON.pretty_generate(json_array)
```

for the two output lines above produces valid JSON that is human-readable, but verbose:

```
[
  {
    "dat": "2013-09-01T20:40:00-07:00",
    "sca": "5",
    "del": "755",
    "dir": "S"
  },

(more lines...)
```

Better from a human-readbiility standpoint would be to have a "record" on each line:

```
[
  {"dat":"2013-09-01T20:40:00-07:00","sca":"5","del":"755","dir":"S"},
  {"dat":"2013-09-01T21:00:00-07:00","sca":"5","del":"459","dir":"S"} 
]
```

But in order to avoid the trailing comma issue [apparently a common problem - see http://trailingcomma.com/ ] I have resorted to an ugly loop with special casing. While it accomplishes the goal, I'm not happy about it and I feel like there must be a simpler way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# expected input:   file of hashes, one/line
# output:       properly formatted json array

require 'json'

prevHash = ""
currHash = ""

puts "["

while input = ARGF.gets
    # in order to to prevent a dangling comma on last element in output json array
    # this counter-intuitive loop always outputs the prev, not the current, array elem
    # with a trailing comma
    input.each_line do |currLine|
        currHash = eval(currLine)   # convert string to hash
        if (prevHash != "")     # if not first time thru
            puts "  " + prevHash.to_json + ","
        end
        prevHash = currHash
    end  
end
# then, finally add the last array element *without* the troublesome trailing comma
puts "  " + currHash.to_json 

puts "]"
```

Suggestions welcome, particularly those that show me the artful one-liner that I missed.

Answer (score 4):

JSON.pretty_generate accepts an [optional hash parameter](http://apidock.com/ruby/JSON/generate) where you can configure the generator.

A state hash can have the following keys:

- **indent**: a string used to indent levels (default: ”),
- **space**: a string that is put after, a : or , delimiter (default: ”),
- **space_before**: a string that is put before a : pair delimiter (default: ”),
- **object_nl**: a string that is put at the end of a JSON object (default: ”),
- **array_nl**: a string that is put at the end of a JSON array (default: ”),
- **allow_nan**: true if NaN, Infinity, and -Infinity should be generated, otherwise an exception is thrown if these values are encountered. This options defaults to false.
- **max_nesting**: The maximum depth of nesting allowed in the data structures from which JSON is to be generated. Disable depth checking with :max_nesting => false, it defaults to 19.

Playing around with that the closest I could get to your requirement is

```
JSON.pretty_generate(hash, {object_nl: '', indent: ' '})
```

which renders to

```
[
 {  "dat": "2013-09-01T20:40:00-07:00",  "sca": "5",  "del": "755",  "dir": "S"},
 {  "dat": "2013-09-01T21:00:00-07:00",  "sca": "5",  "del": "459",  "dir": "S"}
]
```

Comment: Actually, simply adding {object_nl: '', indent: ''} which are, theoretically, the default values, gets very close to the desired output. It is not at all clear to me why this is so.